# Agreement with person now fired, can I still call on it?

Tags: work-environment, ex-colleagues

For the past two years I have been allowed to bring my dog to work for 2 weeks a year. This agreement was made with my manager and the HR manager.

Unfortunately, one has switched jobs and the other was fired today. I will need to bring the dog with me tomorrow and the coming 2 weeks.

What is the best wat to approach this?
Just take him, and mention the agreement if the new manager complains? Is it still valid?
Ask again?

I can't really handle no for an answer at the moment as everything is already arranged and there are no doggy daycares or kennels in the area. The only thing I could propose is me working from home for the period of 2 weeks, which is certainly possible but not usually wished for.

Last times went very well, he just sleeps the whole day and doesn't bother anyone. No allergies as far as I know but I can easily change desks if that's the case.

Comment: If worst comes to worst, have you got an email OKing the arrangement?

Comment: @kozaky I have the email where I ask, and then HR calling me over. The rest was mouth-mouth. However 'm positive the now fired HR manager is willing to 'testify' that he gave the OK.

Comment: As long as he wasn't fired for letting you bring your dog to work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This somewhat depends on the rules and customs in your company, but usually the general rule is:

> The decisions of a manager are not automatically invalidated if the manager is fired.

Think about it: Otherwise the new manager would have to re-write or re-confirm *every single decision* and regulation the old manager set up, even ones from years ago - that just would not be practical.

Of course there are exceptions - for example, if a manager was fired for a specific infraction, decisions linked to that infraction will likely be overturned. For example, hypothetically speaking, if the old manager messed up the assignment of employees to projects, the new manager will probably re-assign various employees. But as long as an old decisions does not cause problems, there is generally no reason to change it.

So, absent any special indications, you can probably assume that the permission your manager gave you is still valid.

If you are uncertain, you could of course ask your new manager about it once someone has been appointed. In the mean time, you could cover your back by asking your colleagues whether they see any problem with you bringing your dog - if they all agree it's fine it seems unlikely your manager would object.

Comment: +1 You don't make an agreement with the person, you do so with the company.

Comment: @rath makes the most important point.  The agreement is with the company.

Answer (score 2):

Carry on as you did before and then deal with any issues as and when they arise.

I assume you have some kind of email/note from your manager/HR indicating that your dog is acceptable to be in the office.

Obviously, your co-workers will continue to be ok with you doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Bring the dog along like normal tomorrow. In case the manager raises an eyebrow about it or asks questions, mention you had an agreement in place with his predecessor for the past 2 years (don't forget to explain why the dog can't simply stay home).

If your new boss isn't OK with continuing the former deal (very unlikely unless he or she's allergic), politely ask for a few hours or the day off so you can sort out the situation.

(If anything you're in luck, in the sense that the dog will arrive tomorrow rather than out of the blue in 6 months.)